# PIC 16F877A toggle half of the leds when button is pressed

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

In this simple circuit, there is a button connected to the A0 pin.

[image: PIC toggle LED's]

I'd like to toggle half of the LED's when button is pressed.

```
#include <pic.h>

#ifndef _XTAL_FREQ
// Clock frequency is 16 Mhz
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#endif

__CONFIG (FOSC_HS & WDTE_OFF & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);

int main()
{
    static char flashingLeds = 0xFF;

    ADCON1 = 0x06;        // RA0 digital input
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1; // RA0 input

    TRISB = 0;    // PORTB is output
    PORTB = 0;    // Make all pins on PORTB low

    while(1)
    {
        // If button is pressed reverse LED's
        if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 1)
        {
            __delay_ms(250);
            flashingLeds = ~flashingLeds;
        }
        PORTB = flashingLeds;
    }
}
```

When button is pressed the program toggles all of the LED's on and off.

On the other hand I want to toggle only half of the lights. When I change flashingLeds variable to **0x0F** it doesn't work as it should.

```
static char flashingLeds = 0x0F;
```

When I change the variable to 0x0F and when the button is pressed, I expect half of the LED's should be on. In binary notation as follows :

> b 0000 1111

After some time I pressed the button again LED's should switch to this state.

> b 1111 0000

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Update:** After making the recommend changes the code became like this. Just for testing purposes, I gave different values to `flashingLEDS` variable. Like `0xF0`, `0xAA`, `0x0F` etc.

```
#include <pic.h>

#ifndef _XTAL_FREQ
// Clock frequency is 16 Mhz
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#endif

__CONFIG (FOSC_HS & WDTE_OFF & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);

int main()
{
    static char flashingLeds = 0xAA;

    ADCON1 = 0x06;        // RA0 digital input
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1; // RA0 input

    TRISB = 0;    // PORTB is output
    PORTB = 0;    // Make all pins on PORTB low

    while(1)
    {
        // If button is pressed reverse LED's
        if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 1)
        {
            __delay_ms(250);
            flashingLeds = ~flashingLeds;
        }
        PORTB ^= flashingLeds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Input is PORT output is LAT.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `it doesn't work as it should`

Comment: I've added a little more explanation to the question. I think the micro controller which I use (which is PIC16F877A) doesn't have port named LAT.

Comment: Can you step through the code in MPLAB?  What is happening with `flashingLeds = ~flashingLeds`?

Comment: You may want to make `flashingLeds` an `unsigned char` so that the compiler doesn't think it needs to do additional range checks.

Comment: Changing `flashingLeds` to `static unsigned char` works for some values `0x0F` but doesn't work for `0xF0` or `0xAA`. I do not have MPLAB installed. I write code in Emacs under Linux and compile using Microchip MPLAB XC8 C compiler.

Comment: I would really try and get the MPLAB X IDE installed.  You will learn a lot about what goes on inside the chip!  No more guessing!

Comment: As a guess, make sure optimization is turned off.

Comment: I've passed `--OPT=none` flag to the compiler. Apparently this change made no difference.

Comment: Move the the delay_ms(250); to _after_ toggling the LEDs, so they will change as soon as you hit the button and the subsequent delay will debounce the switch. Then remove the 100nF capacitor from the switch circuit (where it could glitch the power supply) and put it between Vcc and gnd, where it will help to prevent glitches.

Comment: @Aaron I've tried Microchip's MPLAB X IDE. It works as if there is a potato sack on the RAM. It doesn't support original PICkit2 which I've bought a long time ago. People are now offering open source electronic projects. You might buy two USB to TTL UART programmer for the price of one PIC microcontroller. I don't like Microhip's end user policy. Lots of people that I know have now switched to 32 bit microcontrollers like STM32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of @Bruce Abbott.

I put the 100nF capacitor between Vcc and ground. I moved the  `delay_ms(250);` to after toggling the LEDs.

The solution was xoring `flashingLeds` to hexadecimal `0xFF` value.

The correct working code is as follows.

```
#include <pic.h>

#ifndef _XTAL_FREQ
// Clock frequency is 16 Mhz
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#endif

__CONFIG (FOSC_HS & WDTE_OFF & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);

int main()
{
    static char flashingLeds = 0xAA;

    ADCON1 = 0x06;        // RA0 digital input
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1; // RA0 input

    TRISB = 0;    // PORTB is output
    PORTB = 0;    // Make all pins on PORTB low

    while(1)
    {
        // If button is pressed reverse LED's
        if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 1)
        {
            /*  change recommended by @bruce-abbott */
           flashingLeds = ~flashingLeds;
            __delay_ms(250);
        }

        PORTB = flashingLeds ^ 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:
PORTB ^= flashingleds; (instead of "=")
With flashingleds being 0x0f. You only have to set ones, where You want to toggle, no need for changing this variable every time.

Whay happens is, that when You do ~0x0f You get 0xf0, so toggling half to on and half to off. When You do what I suggest - You will be xoring half of the port, so this is what was needed.

Another approach could be to set half of the port:
PORTB |= flashingleds
and in the next cycle:
PORTB &= ~flashingleds.

Look that I'm never directly writing to port by "=" - always or, xor, and. This is used to not disturb the other half of port.

Reading of port state is ok, checked in RM.

Comment: First of all thanks. When `flashingLeds = 0x0F;` your solution works fine. But when I change `flashingLeds` to `0xAA` or `0xF0` it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What does mean "sometimes"? What is happening? It does nothing or something strange?

Comment: Is your switch actually wired like that or is it a mistake on the circuit diagram?

Comment: Let's say if I make `flashingLeds = 0xF0;` . I first pressed button nothing happened. Second press still LED's are in first state. In third press LED's changed state and switched back.  I made `flashingLeds = 0xAA` First press they switched to `0x33` as expected. Second press they are still in `0x33' state, they didn't change their state. Third try still `0x33`. In forth press they switched to `0xAA`

Comment: Problem is in Your switch connection. Resistor should be right on the pin to pull it up. Check this. Alternatively You can turn on internal pullup on switch pin (but in this case not possible - IT seems that PORTA doesnt have pullup)

Comment: What actually happens is, that It doesnt detect some switch edges and sometimes detects more than one. adding 100nF cap from switch pin to ground will also get rid of bumping contacts.

Comment: I updated the schematics. The right one is as above.

Comment: Is code also up to date?

Comment: I've updated the code. And add a 100nF capacitor between switch pin to ground. But apparently there is no change.

Comment: Do not change flashingleds. Just do PORTB ^= flashingleds when button is detected. ^= will do all for You

Comment: Just put this in Your while: // If button is pressed reverse LED's
        if (PORTAbits.RA0 = 1){  _delay_ms (250); 
PORTB ^= flashingLeds;        }

Comment: Thanks but after making this change LED's don't change their state.

Comment: i will test this on my hardware and post results on morning

Comment: I missed "==" in if() statement - should be if(PORTAbits.RA0 == 1)

Comment: @fifi_22 Note that something like `PORTB ^= flashingleds` is a read-modify-write instruction which can lead to bugs on the older 16F PIC's like the OP is using. (They added the LAT registers in newer PIC's to solve this). Shadowing the values for the output ports like the OP is trying to do is actually the preferred method on these older devices.

Comment: Oj,  didn't know that. I used this everywhere in PIC and also AVR. Thank for pointing that out.

Comment: @fifi_22 I already made comparison statement with two equal signs. Thanks for the helping efforts.